# Mac Commands for Dummies

Tags: mac, macbook, macbook-pro

I recently got a MacBook Pro from the company I work for.
After being an avid PC user for over 10 years, now I find myself getting frustrated with the different shortcuts.
On PC I was able to move around without much need of a mousepad, so much that my fingers are trained to go places that Macs don't understand.
Is there a site where I can find all these commands?

Even better, is there a way that I can modify this Mac to answer to commands similarly as with PC?

Comment: please note that users are supposed to do their own research before asking here. I'm sure that looking for "mac keyboard shortcuts" would give you plenty of results.

Comment: Please don't try to make your Mac work like a PC -- it won't work very well, you'll just make something that doesn't work like either a Mac *or* a PC. Yes, there's a painful period as you learn different shortcuts, but you'll get the hang of it. If you try to PC-ize the Mac, you'll never get the hang of it and be stuck with a mutant config forever.

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences:Keyboard:Keyboard Shortcuts - then read what it tells you for how to change them.

...annnd https://www.xkcd.com/934/

Answer (score 0):

Can you "remap" Apple keyboard shortcuts so that the mimic Windows?

Sure.  But, I highly discourage you from doing so.

One of the nice things about Apple is that they have a standardized UI "doctrine" that, for the most part, all developers have adhered to.

<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is copy *everywhere.*  <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is not mapped to anything so it's very possible to map this to "copy" to mimic a PC.  However, many 3rd party apps may implement the <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> shortcut for a different function.

(<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> which is "bold" in Windows is the command to tell tmux to accept commnands in macOS)

I personally run macOS, Windows 10, and FreeBSD.  I can assure you that after a short while of using macOS, you will adjust quite easily.

Apple support also has a listing of [Mac Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201236) you may wish to reference.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the MacMost site where you can find a nice, color-coded, printable PDF sheet incorporating all the Mac keyboard shortcuts.  Listen to the advice NOT to remap your keyboard. In fact, if you do go to the MacMost site, take the time to look around at the numerous short but very informative videos he has there on a multitude of Apple/Mac topics.